# Changing the color and length of each level of a tree

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I have an adapted code below for a tree. When the length of boxes is set globally the alignment was fine. However, it takes more space as text in some boxes are taken two line. So, I want the color and length adjustment to be per level. I want the letters to be Just a single line for each box as in the code.
Please help on this, thank you. Here is the code as refereed above:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{
    my node style/.style={
        font=\tiny,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!25,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        % minimum size=4mm,
        draw=blue!75,
        very thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=justify,
        % level 2/.style={text width=3.5cm},
    }
}
\forestset{
    my tree style/.style={
        for tree={grow=east,
            parent anchor=east, % <---
            child anchor=west,  % <---
            my node style,
            l sep=1.5em,
            % text width=3.5cm,  %<---turn off all sizing
            %                   text width=5cm,
            forked edge,                % <---
            fork sep=1em,               % <---
            edge={draw=blue!50, thick},                
            if n children=3{for children={
                    if n=2{calign with current}{}}
            }{},
            %       delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
            tier/.option=level,
        }
    }
}
\centering
\begin{forest}
    my tree style
    [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y Euro Pallet
    [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y, text width=4cm %<---changed
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    ]
    [Inicialização de sistema Inicialização de sistema Acção Y
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização Inicialização de sistema de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema de sistema de sistema]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The image is:

[image: Code output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the color and text width depend on the level, you can use

```
        where level=0{my node=blue,text width=6em}{},
        where level=1{my node=purple,text width=5em}{},
        where level=2{my node=red,text width=4em}{},
```

Note that I slightly redefined `my node`. I do not know whether these are the text widths you had in mind.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{
    my node/.style={
        font=\tiny,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=#1!25,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        % minimum size=4mm,
        draw=#1!75,
        very thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=justify,
        % level 2/.style={text width=3.5cm},
    }
}
\forestset{
    my tree style/.style={
        for tree={grow=east,
            parent anchor=east, % <---
            child anchor=west,  % <---
        where level=0{my node=blue,text width=6em}{},
        where level=1{my node=purple,text width=5em}{},
        where level=2{my node=red,text width=4em}{},
            l sep=1.5em,
            % text width=3.5cm,  %<---turn off all sizing
            %                   text width=5cm,
            forked edge,                % <---
            fork sep=1em,               % <---
            edge={draw=blue!50, thick},                
            if n children=3{for children={
                    if n=2{calign with current}{}}
            }{},
            %       delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
            tier/.option=level,
        }
    }
}
\centering
\begin{forest}
    my tree style
    [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y Euro Pallet
    [Inicialização de sistema Acção Y%, text width=4cm %<---changed
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    ]
    [Inicialização de sistema Inicialização de sistema Acção Y
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização Inicialização de sistema de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema]
    [Inicialização de sistema de sistema de sistema]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the sizes to be such that the texts just fit in a single line, please let me know. This can also be done.

Comment: Dear Schrödinger's cat, Thank you so much. I really appreciate your effort. You have been able to solve one of the problem. yes, I want the sizes to be such that the texts just fit in a single line. I will like to also be able to define the size per level to ensure that they are well aligned. Thank you so much.

Comment: Dear Schrödinger's cat, Thank you so much. I really appreciate your effort. You have been able to solve the problem. Yes, I want the sizes to be such that the texts just fit in a single line and well-aligned. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Easy I will try to do that later. I am sitting at a machine in which I cannot edit codes containing `ç` or `ã`. However, `where level=0{my node=blue}{},
        where level=1{my node=purple,text width={width("Inicialização de sistema Inicialização de sistema Acção Y")}}{},
        where level=2{my node=red,text width={width("Inicialização Inicialização de sistema de sistema")}}{},` should work, I just cannot test right now.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat, It Works. Thank you so much. Best regards.